# margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto not working on input

Tags: css, html

I have an input in a form that I am trying to align in the center. Usually `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right: auto` fail to respond when `display: block` isn't added to the CSS. I have added `display: block` to my CSS but still it isn't display as I would like it to.

I've made a JSFiddle to keep easier to understand: http://jsfiddle.net/XnKDQ/97/

Comment: Your jsfiddle link doesn't seem to work.  As a suggestion, does the item have a fixed width specified - I believe that this is also required for this approach.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

In order for `margin: 0 auto;` to work, in addition to `display:block` a `width` needs to be specified.

Comment: Don't forget display: block either, you'd think it'd be display: inline-block, but nope... That breaks it

Comment: @Clarence if you read the question carefully, you can see, that Xecure already applied `display:block;` to the element. That's why i did not mention that.

Comment: Right, I'm just saying reading your answer on its own it's not mentioned, and even comparing the question and your answer it doesn't directly follow that the `display: block` was relevant. I think if you prepended your answer with, "In addition to display: block, in order for..."

Comment: @clarence I added an according comment to leave no doubts, I hope you are happy now;) if you are, feel free to upvote;-D

Comment: make sure you're not accidently `float: left`ing as well ... d'oh

Comment: @Christoph Why is this?

Answer (score 9):

In my case, it was `float: left` that I forgot about. So, make sure you apply `float: none` to your input field.

You already have `display: block` and `margin: 0 auto`, you just need to set width too.

Example that should work:

```
input{
     width:50% !important;
     margin:0 auto !important;
     display:block !important;
     float:none !important;
}
```

If that doesn't work try adding `!important` to the values or make sure your style is not overwritten by something else.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution for you

you should specify element **width**

```
input {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have can do something like this:

```
input {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the three forms together to be aligned in the center? Wrap them in a single div and center that div instead.

Comment: I'm trying to align the <input> in the center of the form

Answer (score 0):

in addition to specifying width and display block also check if the float property is set to none.

Answer (score 0):

In addiction to everything, you may check if your body have the parameter position. It may be set to fixed.