# Align right input form in wordpress right sidebar

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mailchimp

I have a MailChimp for WordPress plugin with form code as such

```
<p>
    <label>Get new posts delivered to your inbox!</label>
    <input type="email" id="my-input" name="EMAIL" align="right" placeholder="Your email address" required />
</p>

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
</p>
```

It looks like this on the sidebar:

[image]

It seems everything is correctly right aligned within the sidebar except my input form. There is a right margin that I cannot get rid of.

I can put customer CSS like so, but it doesn't so anything.

```
#my-input {
    text-align: right; /* This works */
    margin-right: 0px; /* This doesn't work */
}
```

Any tips to edit either the HTML or the custom CSS to get this working?

Comment: give the input box display block maybe it works

Comment: Could you give the website link?

Comment: @Momin Here is an example http://biketoeverything.com/2018/01/01/secure-your-bike-for-any-kind-of-excursion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my specific case, the solution was

```
#my-input {
    width: 100%; /* Somehow width was not already 100% by default */
}
```

Maybe it was something in the [Customizr](https://wordpress.org/themes/customizr/) Wordpress theme I was using that messed it up.

Thanks @BM RAFIQ for giving me code to try, if width 100% doesn't work for you try some of the other code he wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
#my-input {
    text-align: right; 
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! The solution was just `width: 100%`! For some reason my input form was by default not filling out the entire space. I think it might've been some weird issue with the Wordpress theme I was using.

Answer (score 1):

paste this

```
   #my-input {

margin-left: 320px !important;

width: 50%; }
```

you can check out here  https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FPP4AWLPX1NP

Comment: It seems this is forcing the left margin to be larger to push it over. It did work when I put `margin-left: 22px` (no need for the `!important`), but it seems a bit hacky. I found my issue seemed to be with the width.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use margin for input tag you have to specified `width` and using `display:block`. look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226151/margin-left-auto-and-margin-right-auto-not-working-on-input?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) it may help you.

another way which I don't recommend is using `!important`. you can add `margin-right:0px !important;` in css.